# Vertically centering text within an inline-block

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, centering, css

I'm trying to create some buttons for a website using styled hyperlinks. I have managed to get the button looking how I want, bar one slight issue. I can't get the text ('Link' in the source code below) to vertically center.

Unfortunately there may be more than one line of text as demonstrated with the second button so I can't use `line-height` to vertically center it.

My initial solution was to use `display: table-cell;` rather than `inline-block`, and that sorts the issue in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not in Internet Explorer so I'm thinking I need to stick to inline-block.

How would I go about vertically centering the link text within the `57px` x `100px` `inline-block`, and have it cater to multiple lines of text? Thanks in advance.

```css
.button {
    background-image:url(/images/categorybutton-off.gif);
    color:#000;
    display:inline-block;
    height:57px;
    width:100px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.button:hover {
    background-image:url(/images/categorybutton-on.gif);
}
.button:before {
    content:"Click Here For\A";
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="button">Link</a>
<a href="/" class="button">Link<br />More Details</a>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wrap your text with a span (Centered), and write another empty span just before it(Centerer) like this.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="..." class="button">
  <span class="Centerer"></span>
  <span class='Centered'>Link</span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.Centered
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.Centerer
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/xVnQ6/

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, unfortunately this doesn't work. The 'Link' line of text appears to be 57px in height and causes the secondary line of text (More Details) to appear outside of the 57px x 100px box. It also ignores the .button:before text.

Comment: Ive uploaded a fiddle for you. with some minor etid.. tell me if it work for you now.

Comment: This looks like a hack! Can someone explain how this work?

Comment: `vertical_align` defines the alignment between siblings (and not between parent and child). So we create the first element and set his height to 100% (its an element with 0 width) and we center the second element (and now it makes the second element centered wirhin the parent) because the first element and the parent have the same height.

Answer (score 37):

Many thanks @avrahamcool, works like a charm!

I have a little upgrade. You can replace redundant .Centerer span with css

```css
.button:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/modernweb/bXD2V/

NOTE: This will not work with text in "content" attribute.

Comment: this one did not work for me! Probably something is wrong, it did made a little change.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this upgrade will not work if you put any text in "content" attribute.

Comment: Worth noting this demo seems to work only if the containing button div is of a fixed height. Text will float to top otherwise - see what happens when changing `height` to `min-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/6ne3aub8/1/

Comment: @VivekGani initial question was about fixed height inline-block element, so I'm not sure why you expect that it will work for dynamic height?

Comment: You don't need the spans though...

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to create any wrapper elements or anything for this... just use inline flex (or grid, but I'll describe flex) and center stuff, like this (it's just the same as doing it with non-inline flex, but with an added `vertical-align` to set a sane baseline for the element):

```css
    .button { 
      display: inline-flex; 
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="/" class="button">Link</a>
    <a href="/" class="button">Link<br />More Details</a>
```

This will also work for dynamic height content.

---

Going through each of those; so first there's the obvious one:

```
display: inline-flex;
```

Next, since `::before` is being used, there are two child items (the `::before` and the text). Since I guess we want them vertically stacked, we'll need to set the direction (because default is "row"):

```
flex-direction: column;     /* PS: this defines the "main" axis */
```

Then, since we want the elements packed and centered along the *vertical* aka *column* aka *main* axis (if you use the "row" flex direction, you'd use `align-content` here instead):

```
justify-content: center;
```

And since we want to center the text, with each line individually centered (remember that each item defaults to filling the *cross* aka *horizontal* axis, so they're already full width):

```
text-align: center;
```

Technically this is enough, except since this is an inline element the baselines will be all over the place (based on content), so we can set them to something consistent and reasonable:

```
vertical-align: middle;   /* align *this* element in the *parent*! */
```

And that's it; just applied directly to the element. No inner divs or wrappers or anything needed.

If you've only got one child element (e.g. no `::before` or whatever) then it doesn't really matter what the flex direction is, so you can shorten the CSS a bit by using the defaults:

```
/* if there's just one child, or you want to */
/* arrange children horizontally: */
.button {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can also drop `vertical-align` if the element's container is positioning it acceptably and you don't need to tweak the baseline.

---

By the way, the same can be done with an inline grid layout if you prefer -- a single-row/column grid has a lot of functional overlap with flex:

```
/* using grid instead: */
.button { 
  display: inline-grid;
  grid: max-content / auto; 
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
/* this is the important bit: */
/* ------------------------------------------------------*/

.button { 
  display: inline-flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------*/




/* other styling from OP; not relevant to the centering. */
/* important props removed & displayed above instead.    */    

.button {
    background-image:url(/images/categorybutton-off.gif);
    color:#000;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    height:57px;
    width:100px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    /*text-align:center;*/
    text-decoration:none;
    /*vertical-align:middle;*/
}
.button:hover {
    background-image:url(/images/categorybutton-on.gif);
}
.button:before {
    content:"Click Here For\A";
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    white-space:pre;
}
/* placeholders for missing images: */
.button { background-color: #AAA; }
.button:hover { background-color: #DDD; }
```

```html
this <a href="/" class="button">Link</a> is
<a href="/" class="button">Link<br />More Details</a> text

<br/><br/>
<a href="/" class="button" style="width:unset;height:unset;padding:1em;">......... fixed sizes ........</a>
<a href="/" class="button" style="width:unset;height:unset;padding:1em;">are<br/><br/><br/>not<br/><br/><br/>required</a>
```

Comment: Great answer. IMO this is now the best answer in 2022 - it will work across all modern browsers. +1 for avoiding use of hidden/pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off the other answers, in case anyone's designing a button and seeking this page one can combine:

- the `button` design with `display:inline-flex`
- a `button-content` div nested within with `display:inline-block`
- a `button-text` span to define things like text-decoration overrides (necessary for buttons not to have underlined text in pages where parent elements define it - notably on chrome & safari)

[demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ne3aub8/9/)