# Trying to horizontally align and center an image next to a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

Would love to have a way to center and horizontally align my header image with the div holding my social media and statement next to it. For the life of me I can't figure it out.

You will see that inside the social div I have my links butted up next to each other but I don't know how to accomplish all this centering simply. Here's the code:

```
<header>
<a href="index.html"><img class="imghdr" src="images/logo.png" alt="SWC Marketing logo" width="358" height="90"/></a>
<div id="social">
<p style="color:white;">My Social Handle</p>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/scottieclifton" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" src="images/social/media/twitter_bx.png" alt="twitter" border="0" width="40" height="40"></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/scottwclifton" target="_blank"><img class="facebook" src="images/social/media/facebook_bx.png" alt="facebook" border="0" width="40" height="40"></a>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/swcmarketing" target="_blank"><img class="linkedin" src="images/social/media/linkedin_bx.png" alt="linkedin" border="0" width="40" height="40"></a> 
<a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/107873413246089179835/posts" target="_blank"><img class="google" src="images/social/media/googleplus_bx.png" border="0" alt="googleplus"  width="40" height="40"></a>              
</div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    margin:10px auto 0px auto;
    background-color:blue;
    line-height: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    }

.hdrimg {
    display:block;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: regular;
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    }


#social {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    }

img.twitter{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px; 
}   
img.facebook{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:40px; 
}       
img.linkedin{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:0px; 
}       
img.google{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:40px; 
}   

#social p{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Are you concerned about older browsers? like IE7? in-line blocks or table-cells might work.

Comment: I don't want table-cells personally. I'm not too concerned about IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the same trick for vertically centering elements in other elements.
take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485378/vertically-centering-text-within-an-inline-block/18485534#18485534).

You need to create an empty span before the element you want to center.
this empty span will be called the Centerer.
give the Centerer `display:inline-block; height:100%; vertical-align:middle;`
and for the element you want to center, give `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;`

It's as simple as that.

**Edit:**
This method don't make you specify any static width (px, or even %).
so your layout stays very flexible.

now that you can verticaly align anything within everything..
you can create a simple layout that will achive your header problem.

**Edit 2**

I've created your layout for you.
as you can see.. its a very simple one (I'm using the vertical alignment trick).
http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/N5Q2W/2/
now take this basic layout, and aplly your css to it.

Comment: my #social is stuck in the left corner. I want the #social to HORIZONTALLY center with the .hdrimg. The .hdrimg is working fine.

Comment: I've created a fiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/N5Q2W/2/ this is the basic layout you nned.. improve it to have your full functuality.

Comment: and: your question is also labeled as 'horizontal-alignment', and as I was saying in my answer.. once you covered the horizontal-alignment thing, the rest is pretty easy. your layout was full of flaws.