# How to Mimic Android / iOS square buttons with plain HTML and CSS2?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, vertical-alignment

This seems almost impossible.

I am trying to create HTML/CSS-only square link buttons with text centered inside and without using CSS3.

I have tried variations of every answer I could find about vertically-centering text in an `inline-block`, but nothing that I try fulfills the following constraints:

1. The entire button element must be a link, not just the text.
2. The text inside the button element must be vertically and horizontally-center and wrap nicely if the width of the button element is not wide enough.
3. The height and width of all buttons should be the same.
4. The buttons must be placeable side-by-side horizontally and wrap to the next line below if the width of the browser is reduced or not enough to fit all buttons.
5. To ensure compatibility with older browsers, this solution must **not** require CSS3 (e.g. `display:flex`).

Think something like the side-by-side square buttons on the iOS and Android home screens but using simple and pure HTML/CSS.  The shadowing, gradients, reflections aren't necessary, just the button structures.

I've tried nested divs using `:before` as a trick to vertically-align the text within an `inline-block`, I've tried using `display:table` with rows and cells, and I've even tried `display:flex` but that uses CSS3.  No solution I tried fits all the criteria above.

So I'm wondering, is this even possible without CSS3?  If so, what's the trick as I would have thought something like this would have been very straightforward to accomplish?

Comment: So you're trying to replicate something that, essentially, *requires* CSS3 (android/IOS) with basic CSS2.1....good luck with that.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  Are you confirming it's impossible to do square button links with centered text without using CSS3?

Comment: Oh..centering the text may not be that hard...you can use absolute positioning for that...but the other requirements...probably not. Certainly there is no method of making **all** buttons the same size without setting specific sizes or Js.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  Well, at least one person has done it below using CSS2, so it's certainly possible, although quite complex.

Comment: Oh, I did say that you would need to use fixed sizes...and that the major stumbling clock...if you have text that's too big...it breaks.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  Breaking if text is too big is natural considering same-sized buttons.  There's no physical way around that, if all the buttons need to be the same sized, then if there's any text larger than that size, it will break.  So once I define the optimal fixed button size I need, I will need to make sure all text placed within all the buttons fits.  Considering that's not a problem, do you see a simpler solution than the one proposed so far which is quite complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is possible, but it uses a lot of nested spans!

The craziest CSS used here is `display: table` and `display: inline-block`, so I think you should be pretty safe.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.special-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.special-button:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.special-button-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.special-button-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="special-button">
  <span class="special-button-table">
    <span class="special-button-cell">Text Here</span>
  </span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="special-button">
  <span class="special-button-table">
    <span class="special-button-cell">Longer Text Item Here</span>
  </span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="special-button">
  <span class="special-button-table">
    <span class="special-button-cell">Text Here</span>
  </span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="special-button">
  <span class="special-button-table">
    <span class="special-button-cell">Really Really Long Text Item That Overflows Here</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: This works and meets all the criteria!  Thanks Josh!  It's crazy to think that something as simple as same-sized, text-centered, side-by-side square buttons require this level of complexity prior to CSS3.  Is there by any chance any way to simplify this level of craziness/nested spans and/or avoid div tables in your solution?

Comment: Hmm, yes turns out you can do away with one of the spans. Just hashed it out really quickly without thinking too much :) Updated answer with the improvement. The requirement of vertically centered multiline text in CSS2 does require `display: table` I think - is there a reason you need to avoid that?

Comment: No reason to avoid the div tables, just looking for the simplest solution possible with the least amount of code as there will be lots of buttons.  I know it's possible to vertically-center text inside an `inline-block` but that then affects the other criteria and I was never able to get it to work properly.  For example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485378/vertically-centering-text-within-an-inline-block   Do you see any way to further simplify your answer while meeting all of the criteria?  If not, I'll use what you've created so far because that still fits all the criteria.

Comment: No I don't see another way. I would use this myself for these criteria. I think for variable height text, `display:table` centering is the only option out of all the CSS2 methods. And `display:table` requires all these elements as a minimum: `a` with fixed width and height to hide overflow, first `span` to display table, second `span` to display table-cell. I tried with less and it doesn't work. You could always shorten the classnames.

Comment: OK, thanks so much Josh!  I upvoted your solution, but before I accept it, let me give the simpler `<li>` answer below yours a chance to see if they can fit all the criteria.  Thanks again, you've been great and I'll definitely be using your solution if no one else comes up with something simpler.

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl How did you get on? I'd be interested to know if there is a simpler solution?

Comment: No one submitted a simpler solution that met all the criteria, so I accepted yours.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Ive possibly missed some details due to a very quick skim read - let me know how far off this is.

```
<style>
    .ios li {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #eee;
        padding: 5% 10px 20px 10px;
        width: 100px;
        max-width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        max-height: 100px;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>


<ul class="ios">
    <a href="test.com"><li>short text</li></a>
    <a href="test2.com"><li>much longer lot of text</li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Close, but the text is not vertically-centered.  Your solution seems the simplest so far, although it doesn't meet all the criteria.  Is there any way to vertically-align the text in the center of the buttons?  https://jsfiddle.net/pygfhpdx/1/

Comment: you could change the padding to a % `padding: 5% 10px 20px 10px;` have edited code

Comment: I tried your edit, but the vertical center of the texts do not line up.  Any other ideas?